# Numerical Approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

we aim to find an approximation of exp(x)

a) determine N an integer and g \in (-log(2)/2, log(2)/2] such that x=N*log(2) + g

b) Think of a way to use the Taylor expansion with four terms of exp(x) along the latter relation, to obtain an approximation of exp(x). Explain the rationale behind the decomposition in a)

c) Implement in MATLAB this approximation

d) Calculate an upper bound on the approximation error

e) Compute the latter bound against the actual error with x= -10,-1,-0.1,0.1,1,10.

how can i find such an N and g, when every different values of x has a different N and g?

Here are my current thought process:  for example, looking at the last part (e) of the question, suppose x=-10, then

a good choice of N would be 14, so 14*log(2)= -9.7041 + g which works out to be 0.2959

if x = -1, then a good choice of N would be 1, with 1*log(2) = -0.6931 +g, where g = 0.3069

if x=10, then a good choice of N would be 14*log(2)= 9.7041+g, where g =0.2959

it seems that N = floor(x/log(2)) from the above 3 cases, and g = x-N*log(2).

however, when i tried x=15, then the only choice of N i have is 22 (21 doesn’t work), so it happens to be the ceil(x/log(2)). 
21*log(2)=14.5561
22*log(2)=15.2492

so how am i suppose to exactly answer to the question (a) that to Determine N an integer and g, such that x=N*log(2)+g?

There must be something i am missing greatly or i am reading the question really wrongly.

Comment: The more I read this, the less sense I can make of it.  You seem to have dropped a phrase in the first line.  It should be "we aim to find an approximation of exp(x) over the range _____"  The range selected will change the approximation.  $x$ starts out a variable, but in a it will have a fixed value depending on $N,g$.  The equation is similar to rescaling $x$ into some range, but it doesn't work.  Since a doesn't work, neither does b.  Please check the problem statement.

Comment: You are at the right path. Your choice of $N = \mathrm{floor}(x/\log 2)$ will work. So, I do not understand exactly your problem with the case $x = 15$.

Comment: @RossMillikan The problem is probably about how to implement the function $\exp$ in a digital computer. Then, one first gets rid of the $2$s power (as this will be separately stored in the exponent bits e.g. in IEEE standards), and the rest (the $g$ part) will be the significant digits.

Comment: @lord soth Suppose x= 15, so x/log(2) = 21.6404. So going by the floor(x/log(2)), i have 21.

however, 21*log(2)=14.5561, which means this require g to be 0.4439, which falls outside the specified domain that g has to be within (-log(2)/2,log(2)/2]. 

so the next choice would be 22, so 22*log(2)=15.2492, with g=-0.2492.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers your question: *How ... to determine N an integer and g, such that x=N log(2)+g?*

Instead of taking the floor of $x/\ln 2$ you should round $x/\ln 2$ to the nearest integer, don't know Matlab but Octave has a `round` function, if you do not have such a round function you can use $N(x) = \textrm{floor}(x/\ln 2 + 0.5)\;$ for positive x and $N(x) = -N(-x)$ if x is negative. This will give the values 
$$N(-10)=-14,\quad N(-1) = -1,\quad N(10) = 14,\quad N(15) = 22.$$ 
Because $|x/\ln 2 -N(x)| \le 0.5$ you have $g = x - \ln 2 N(x)  \in [-\ln2 /2, +\ln2 /2]$.

Comment: could you give me a hint for part(b)? how can i use this with the taylor expansion and the decomposition? 

i suspect it would be something to do with the centre of expansion.. but i am stucked

Comment: @bryan: Use the decompostion formula
$$\exp(x) = \exp(N\ln 2 + g)= \exp(N\ln 2 ) \exp(g) = T(N)\exp(g(x))$$
The $T(N)$ can be taken from a lookup-table, and $\exp(g(x))$ with an approximation,
e.g. the Taylor series.

The idea is to compute the Taylor series for **small** arguments. There are two reasons for this: First the approximation is better (the series converges faster) and for large negative x you will get rather big cancellation errors, for example $\exp(-15)\approx 3\times10^{-7}$ but third term is $(-15)^3/3! = -562.5$

Comment: Do you mind elaborating further on 'big cancellation errors'?

Comment: @bryan: Lets assume we calculate with double floats (appr. 16 decimal digits) and 
take $x=-25$, then the largest term in the Taylor expansion is
$(-25)^25/25! = -5726042115.469874$ and $\exp(-25)=0.00000000001388794386496402$ or
$e^{-25} = 0.1388794386496402\times10^{-10}$. The rounding error for computing the first expresssion is about $0.5\times 10^{-6}$ which is much larger than $e^{-25}$. Computing $e^{-25}$ would require computing about 115 terms where all the rounding errors must magically go away, but in practice you will get completely wrong result, even negative values could occur.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 

How did you arrive at the largest term in the Taylor Expansion to be (-25)^25/25!? 

and calculating exp(-25), its value is 1.3888*10^-11, why do you need to compute 115 terms? 

One side question: what is the point of using all these taylor series when our modern computers are able to handle such numbers effectively?

Comment: @bryan - Here my answers: a)  $(-25)^{25}/25!$ is the largest term by numerical inspection **and** theoretical reasons: With $t_k = x^k/k!$ you have $t_k= t_{k-1}\frac{x}{k}$ and therefore $|t_k|$
is increasing until $k>|x|.\quad$
b) ??? Every computing device should give $\exp(-25) \approx 1.38879\times10^{-11}\quad$ 
c) For computing $e^{-25}$ with a relative error $< 10^{-16}$ the terms must be 
$< 0.5\times10^{-16}e^{-25} \approx 6.\times10^{-28}$ and the first one is the 115th.

Comment: @bryan: Just noticed the side question. The point is that the computers 
too use some kind of approximation in their algorithms (either soft- or hardware),
although to necessarily Taylor series, but rational or Chebyshev series 
together with range reduction. I guess your task is a pedagogical one with the
simplest form of range reduction and approximation in the basic interval.

Comment: Thanks, i get it. Now for part (d). my upper bound happens to be 2^N * (sum_(i=4)^infinity g^i/n!), (basically i am taking the remaining term of the taylor series multiplied by N(x)); but this makes my latter bound error = actual error, am i answering the question correctly?

Comment: Kind of. But maybe you should you use
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder for $R_k(x)$ with $k=4, M=\exp(\ln(2)/2)=\sqrt{2}, r=\ln(2)/2$

Comment: Thanks! just to double confirm, for this question my upper bound would be 2^N * M* (r^*(k+1))/(k+1)! right? (basically i have to add the 2^N infront of the reminder estimate)
i presume you choose M=exp(ln(2)/2) since ln(2)/2 is the upper bound of (the range of values of) g.

Comment: Depends on the definition of approximation error. I would not use the $2^N$ term and make clear that it is the error for the basic interval, and that the overall error is a relative error (an absolute error is be rather meaningless for large negative $x$).

Comment: I was thinking of 2^N * reminder estimate because of the last part of the question, where they ask me to compare the latter bound against the actual error. If i only use M*(r^*k+1))/(k+1)!, my latter bound would be much lesser than my actual error, hence i decided to add the 2^N, what is your take on this?

Comment: Makes sense for e).